# How to check another condition before set AtomicBoolean?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

I have an AtomicBoolean and want to set it, if another condition is also true:

For example we have a bankaccount with an **Active** and **Saldo** field. In the method setInctive, I have to check if the **Saldo** field is exactly zero and then set the **Active** field to false.

This is my solution, but I'm not sure if this really works!

```
private final AtomicBoolean active = new AtomicBoolean(true);
private final AtomicReference<Double> saldo = new AtomicReference<>(0.0);

@Override
public boolean setInctive() {
    //First: check if saldo is 0.0
    //Second: set active to false

    saldo.getAndUpdate(aDouble ->  {
        if(aDouble == 0)
            active.set(false);

        return aDouble;
    });

    //return negated value of the active field
    return !active.get();
}
```

What would be a correct solution with atomics and
is this even possible without using locks?

Comment: What is wrong with your algorithm ? Seems ok to me.

Comment: see AtomicStampedReference.  allows you to easily box two values together in one atomic.  or, just use an AtomicReference with an object which contains the boolean and the double.

Comment: @jtahlborn Thank you! This was the right direction. With an AtomicMarkableReference it is possible to check two values (Double and Boolean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to and check another condition and set a boolean, is to use an AtomicMarkableReference. Im my example of type *Double*:

```
private final AtomicMarkableReference<Double> saldo = new AtomicMarkableReference<>(0.0, true);

@Override
public boolean setInctive() {
    return saldo.attemptMark(0.0, false);
}
```

The saldo field now represents not only the current saldo, but also the status of the bank account.